# scrape content generated in html report

Tags: html, jasper-reports

While generating the HTML report from the .jasper file, seems like some scrape html content generated at the end of the report.

Please find the code and output image attached.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version last-->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="dashboard" pageWidth="1000" pageHeight="400" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="990" leftMargin="5" rightMargin="5" topMargin="5" bottomMargin="5" uuid="fc97a963-c0b6-4c19-a348-7e2773e092a3">
    <property name="template.engine" value="tabular_template"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Employee DataSource"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <style name="Table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#EFEFEF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <parameter name="TITLE_PARAM" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[SELECT PLATFORM ,
  STATUS,
  COUNT(STATUS) scount
FROM REPORTSUMMARY
GROUP BY PLATFORM,
  STATUS
  Order by STATUS]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="PLATFORM" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="STATUS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SCOUNT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <variable name="TOTAL_COUNT" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression>
            <![CDATA[$F{SCOUNT}]]>
        </variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="Group1">
        <groupExpression>
            <![CDATA[$F{PLATFORM}]]>
        </groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="43">
                <frame>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="601" y="10" width="298" height="27" forecolor="#336699" backcolor="#336699" uuid="408a7c22-76fa-4a57-9778-3da3f0d6b85f"/>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="1" y="3" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="57125616-aebb-475f-a7ab-16dd8679c9e4"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text>
                            <![CDATA[Status]]>
                        </text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="139" y="4" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="665740eb-5cb8-472a-b6a2-f3e4d31ff9bc"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text>
                            <![CDATA[Count]]>
                        </text>
                    </staticText>
                </frame>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="23">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="602" y="3" width="120" height="20" uuid="5449c62a-338f-4374-b751-31dabc5ba846"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text>
                        <![CDATA[Total]]>
                    </text>
                </staticText>
                <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement x="739" y="3" width="101" height="20" uuid="4085321d-10e9-433d-91eb-d884bd56dd06"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression>
                        <![CDATA[$V{TOTAL_COUNT}]]>
                    </textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band height="360">
            <stackedBarChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report" renderType="draw" theme="default">
                    <reportElement x="90" y="56" width="460" height="280" uuid="09719da3-4b9c-477d-9d90-f88af07d53b8"/>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression>
                            <![CDATA[$F{STATUS}]]>
                        </seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression>
                            <![CDATA[$F{STATUS}]]>
                        </categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression>
                            <![CDATA[$F{SCOUNT}]]>
                        </valueExpression>
                        <labelExpression>
                            <![CDATA[$F{SCOUNT}.toString()]]>
                        </labelExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot isShowLabels="true" isShowTickLabels="true" isShowTickMarks="true">
                    <plot>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="0" color="#FF0000"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="1" color="#FF9900"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="2" color="#FFFF00"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="3" color="#00CC00"/>
                    </plot>
                    <itemLabel/>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </barPlot>
            </stackedBarChart>
        </band>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="250" y="7" width="557" height="40" uuid="73467039-ba9d-4518-9538-cdb4f66731fe"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="24" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression>
                    <![CDATA[CONCATENATE("Summary Report from ",$P{TITLE_PARAM})]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="28">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="602" y="3" width="120" height="20" uuid="b384d934-ac20-4d5e-82e1-e8f755fd5446"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression>
                    <![CDATA[$F{STATUS}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.###;(#,##0.###)">
                <reportElement x="738" y="3" width="102" height="20" uuid="49795f7f-e4c5-4b76-8fe0-2c1905b63e41"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression>
                    <![CDATA[$F{SCOUNT}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="600" y="23" width="300" height="1" uuid="eb500a00-300f-4ffc-bc86-5c5b37439cfb"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

[image]